# Possible to create a factory to instantiate custom Form validators?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

(using Zend Framework 2.2.4)

My validator factory, doesn't seem to "exist" at validation time.  If I attempt to instantiate the validator from the controller in which the form is housed, it conversely works fine:

**This works...**

```
$mycustomvalidator = $this->getServiceLocator()
    ->get('ValidatorManager')
    ->get('LDP_PinAvailable');
```

Here's how things are set up otherwise in the code, I can't seem to find the problem, and was hopeful to avoid opening up ZF2 source to understand.  By way of documentation, it seems right.

**Module Config**

```
public function getValidatorConfig()
{
    return array(
       'abstract_factories' => array(
           '\LDP\Form\Validator\ValidatorAbstractFactory',
       ),
    );
}
```

**Factory Class**

```
namespace LDP\Form\Validator;

use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface,
    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ValidatorAbstractFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        return stristr($requestedName, 'LDP_PinAvailable') !== false;
    }


    public function createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        // baked in for sake of conversation
        $validator = new \LDP\Form\Validator\PinAvailable();

        if( $validator instanceof DatabaseFormValidatorInterface )
            $validator->setDatabase( $locator->get('mysql_slave') );

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

**Custom Validator**

```
namespace LDP\Form\Validator;

class PinAvailable extends \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator implements DatabaseFormValidatorInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql
     */
    private $database;

    public function setDatabase( \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql $db )
    {
        $this->database = $db;
    }


    public function isValid( $value )
    {
        $DBA = $this->database->getAdapter();
        // do the mixed database stuff here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Lastly, the form field validator config part of the array:

```
'pin' => array(
    'required' => true,
        'filters'  => array(
            array('name' => 'alnum'),
            array('name' => 'stringtrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array( 'name' => 'LDP_PinAvailable' )
        ),
    ),
),
```

Piecing it all together, the form loads, and when submitted, it does with the stack trace below:

```
2013-10-28T17:09:35-04:00 ERR (3): Exception:
1: Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for LDP_PinAvailable
Trace:
#0 /Users/Saeven/Documents/workspace/Application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('LDP_PinAvailabl...', true)
#1 /Users/Saeven/Documents/workspace/Application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Validator/ValidatorChain.php(82): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('LDP_PinAvailabl...', Array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging some more, I've found the problem.  It distilled to these lines in Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain circa line 80:

```
public function plugin($name, array $options = null)
{
    $plugins = $this->getPluginManager();
    return $plugins->get($name, $options);
}
```

There was no plugin manager available in context.

It took about three seconds of Googling to find that I had to do this when I prepared the form in the controller:

```
 $validators = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ValidatorManager');
 $chain      = new ValidatorChain();
 $chain->setPluginManager( $validators );
 $form->getFormFactory()->getInputFilterFactory()->setDefaultValidatorChain( $chain );
```

Hopefully this helps someone else. You **are** able to use regular old classnames when setting it up this way, no need to warp the classnames.

Answer (score 4):

The ValidatorPluginManager extends the Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager. The AbstractPluginManager has a feature called "autoAddInvokableClass", which is enabled by default.

Basically, what this means, is that if the service name requested can't be resolved by the ValidatorPluginManager, it will then check if the name is a valid class name. If so, it will simply add it as an invokable class right there, on-demand, which of course means that it will never fall back to your abstract factory.

To circumvent this behavior, the easiest method is to simply make your abstract factory respond to service names that do not actually resolve to the actual class names.

See: [AbstractPluginManager.php#L98-L100](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/3141049e8766043c6153ec7a83062f45ffd5e712/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php#L98-L100)

Comment: Thanks for answering.  This is a bit of a PITA.  Semantically, I'd contend the availability of an abstract factory in a validator config should denote a developer's intentions. No class name resolution.

Comment: It could be a worthwhile discussion / proposition for ZF3. Feel free to create an issue on the ZF2 repo to propose how you think it should behave and why. :)

Comment: Done.  Now, I've changed my validator's service name to use a simple lowercase string.  I can use that string from the controller, e.g.: `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('ldp-validator-pinavailable');`  and it finds it "ok".  When then form attempts to validate though, it fails with Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for ldp-validator-pinavailable

Comment: Thanks for your help today; I unmarked the answer since I've found the solution to not include what was mentioned here about names, but left the up vote for good karma and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In ZF3/Laminas, if a validator is registered as an `invokable`, you can call the validator in the `getInputFilterSpecification()` of your form, and no problem. If a validator is instantiated using a factory, you get into trouble. If I understand correctly, even if your form is registered like this

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        SomeForm::class => SomeFormFactory::class,
    ]
]
```

and your validator:

```
'validators' => [
    'factories' => [
        SomeValidator::class => SomeValidatorFactory::class,
    ]    
]
```

you won't be instantiating the validator via factory. The reason is that the form factory (the one you get like `$form->getFormFactory()`) has an input filter factory and in there sits default validator chain. And this validator chain has no `ValidatorManager` attached. And without the `ValidatorManager`, the default chain cannot map the validator name to the validator factory.

To solve all this headache, in your controller factory do this:

```
$form->('FormElementManager')->get(SomeForm::class);
$form->getFormFactory()->getInputFilterFactory()
        ->getDefaultValidatorChain()->setPluginManager($container->get('ValidatorManager'));
```

and your troubles are over.