# Custom validator not found by ValidatorPluginManager

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I'm struggling with getting my custom validator to work.
The thing is I have a custom form element that uses a custom validator.
But when field is being created the ValidatorPluginManager fails to find my custom validator.
Now I know that it's a scope issue but I can' resolve it.

Error message:

```
A plugin by the name "AliasExists" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager
```

Validator code:

```
class AliasExists
    extends AbstractValidator
    implements AdapterAwareInterface
{
    use AdapterAwareTrait;

    const NOT_UNIQUE = 'notUnique';

    /**
     * Validation failure message templates definition
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $messageTemplates = [
        self::NOT_UNIQUE => "Entry with alias %value% already exists",
    ];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table;

    /**
     * @var Select
     */
    protected $select;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $categoryField = 'category';

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $categoryValue;

    public function __construct($options)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);

        if ($options instanceof Traversable) {
            $options = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($options);
        } elseif ($options instanceof Adapter) {
            $temp = [];
            $temp['adapter'] = $options;
            $options = $temp;
        } else {
            if (func_num_args() > 1) {
                $options = func_get_args();
                $firstArgument = array_shift($options);
                if (is_array($firstArgument)) {
                    $temp = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($firstArgument);
                } else {
                    $temp['table'] = $firstArgument;
                }

                if (!empty($options)) {
                    $temp['adapter'] = array_shift($options);
                }

                $options = $temp;
            }
        }

        if (array_key_exists('table', $options)) {
            $this->setTable($options['table']);
        }

        if (array_key_exists('adapter', $options)) {
            $this->setAdapter($options['adapter']);
        }
    }

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        if (null === $this->adapter) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('No database adapter set.');
        }

        if (empty($this->table)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Table has not been set.');
        }

        $valid = true;
        $this->setValue($value);

        if ($context) {
            // TODO
        }

        $result = $this->query($value);
        if (!$result) {
            $valid = false;
            $this->error(self::NOT_UNIQUE);
        }

        return $valid;
    }

    public function getSelect()
    {
        if ($this->select instanceof Select) {
            return $this->select;
        }

        $select = new Select();
        $table = new TableIdentifier($this->table);
        $select->from($table);
        $select->where->equalTo(
            'alias',
            null
        );
        if (!empty($this->categoryField) && !empty($this->categoryValue)) {
            $select->where->equalTo(
                $this->categoryField,
                $this->categoryValue
            );
        }
        $select->columns(['id']);

        $this->select = $select;

        return $this->select;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the set adapter
     *
     * @return Adapter
     */
    public function getAdapter(): Adapter
    {
        return $this->adapter;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a (new) DB adapter
     *
     * @param Adapter $adapter
     * @return self Provides a fluent interface
     */
    public function setAdapter(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        return $this->setDbAdapter($adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the set table
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTable(): string
    {
        return $this->table;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a (new) table
     *
     * @param string $table
     * @return self Provides a fluent interface
     */
    public function setTable(string $table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
        $this->select = null;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryField(): string
    {
        return $this->categoryField;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $categoryField
     */
    public function setCategoryField(string $categoryField)
    {
        $this->categoryField = $categoryField;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCategoryValue(): int
    {
        return $this->categoryValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $categoryValue
     */
    public function setCategoryValue(int $categoryValue)
    {
        $this->categoryValue = $categoryValue;
    }

    protected function query($value)
    {
        $sql = new Sql($this->getAdapter());
        $select = $this->getSelect();
        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $parameters = $statement->getParameterContainer();
        $parameters['where1'] = (string)$value;
        $result = $statement->execute();

        return $result->current();
    }
}
```

Validator factory:

```
class AliasExistsFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $db = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);

        return new AliasExists($db);
    }
}
```

Custom form element code:

```
class Alias
    extends Text
    implements InputProviderInterface
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'alias',
        'required' => 'required',
        'class' => 'form-control',
    ];

    protected $label = 'Alias';

    public function __construct($name = null, array $options = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->setAttribute('id', $this->getName());
    }

    public function getInputSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
                ['name' => 'StringToLower'],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                    'options' => [
                        'type' => 'string'
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'Regex',
                    'options' => [
                        'pattern' => '/^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+$/',
                        'messages' => [
                            Regex::NOT_MATCH => 'Only numbers, underscore, dash and characters from A to Z are allowed'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => [
                        'min' => 1,
                        'max' => 255
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'AliasExists', <--- Custom validator
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

module.config.php

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        Form\Element\Alias::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
],
'validators' => [
    'factories' => [
        Validator\AliasExists::class => Factory\AliasExistsFactory::class,
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'AliasExists' => Validator\AliasExists::class,
    ]
]
```

Controller factory that instantiates form that has this custom field:

```
class EditControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {

        $formManager = $container->get('FormElementManager');
        $form = $formManager->get(ArticleForm::class);

        return new EditController($form);
    }
}
```

The only way I can get my custom validator to work is (as found in this answer [Possible to create a factory to instantiate custom Form validators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642139/possible-to-create-a-factory-to-instantiate-custom-form-validators)) is to set validator chain in controller factory that instantiates form but its an overkill to have to do this in every controller factory that could possibly have a form that uses this field that has custom validator in it.

Comment: The querstion you've linked is indeed a way to solve this issue and pretty much the way I solved it aswell. Created a factory for the inputFilter to inject the dependency of the ValidatorPluginManager. The problem is with the inputFilter creating a new ValidatorPluginManager. The InputFilter that is created by Zend should inject the ValidatorPluginManager containing your configuration but this doesn't happen and can be seen as bug maybe. Not sure whether or not there is already an issue on the Github repository for Zend\Validator.

Comment: Could you spare some code? :) 
And please post it as answer so I can check it as answered.

Comment: Well in your case you're working with InputFilterSpecifications and I don't know whether the validatePluginManager is injected properly in that case into the element. It does inject properly for the InputFilter classes. I can provide some code for that but that is not the stuff you're looking for, because then you've got to create inputFilters and add the defaults for each of your custom elements. Another way is pass the Adapter into your element, but Forms will also need the dependency, making it a bit of a big tunnel network within your code.

Comment: Making form/element depend on Adapter is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. At this point I decided to postpone implementing the feature I want since project is still not mature enough for it to be mandatory.