# zf2/zf3 register custom validator and injecting it into fieldset

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have a custom validator:

```
class CustomValidator extends RecordExists
{    
    public function isValid($value, array $context = null)
    {
        // some behaviour
        return parent::isValid($value);
    }
}
```

This validator has a factory:

```
class CustomValidatorFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $validator = new CustomValidator();
        // preparations for CustomValidator
        return $validator;
    }
}
```

`CustomValidator` and its factory are registered in `module.config.php` under

```
'validators' => [
    'factories' => [
        CustomValidator::class => CustomValidatorFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

`CustomValidator` is attached to a fieldset's input in `getInputFilterSpecification()` as

```
'validators' => [
    ['name' => CustomValidator::class],
]
```

The fieldset is called via `init()` method of the form, and the form is called in the controller factory as `$container->get('FormElementManager')->get('TheNeededForm')`.

The problem is that for some reason, `CustomValidator` gets instantiated not through the `CustomValidatorFactory`, but `getInputFilterSpecification()` of the fieldset just creates an instance of `new CustomValidator()`.

How to make the custom validator instantiation through the factory?

PS: I already surfed the internet, and found a similar problem, but the solution given there didn't help: it suggested adding `'abstract_factories' => [FormAbstractServiceFactory::class]` in `module.config.php`, under `'form_elements'` directive.

Comment: did you add "Zend\Validator" to config on "modules" key?

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ, yep, was already there.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this question here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61287283/4685379

Here it is:

In ZF3/Laminas, if a validator is registered as an invokable, you can call the validator in the `getInputFilterSpecification()` of your form, and no problem. If a validator is instantiated using a factory, you get into trouble. If I understand correctly, even if your form is registered like this

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        SomeForm::class => SomeFormFactory::class,
    ]
]
```

and your validator:

```
'validators' => [
    'factories' => [
        SomeValidator::class => SomeValidatorFactory::class,
    ]    
]
```

you won't be instantiating the validator via factory. The reason is that the form factory (the one you get like `$form->getFormFactory()`) has an input filter factory and in there sits default validator chain. And this validator chain has no `ValidatorManager` attached. And without the `ValidatorManager`, the default chain cannot map the validator name to the validator factory.

To solve all this headache, in your controller factory do this:

```
$form->('FormElementManager')->get(SomeForm::class);
$form->getFormFactory()->getInputFilterFactory()
    ->getDefaultValidatorChain()->setPluginManager($container->get('ValidatorManager'));
```

and your troubles are over.